# understanding how loop invariants and asserts work in dafny

Tags: dafny

I am trying to understand why the assertion I have below, fails. I can understand that it is because of the loop invariant, but why does Dafny do this? Why does it rely so much on the loop invariant when I have clearly stated the loop condition is while i < n? Is this because Dafny is looking at the verification code first? That is, the invariant line, before it looks at the actual code?

```
method T ()
{
  var n := 10;
  var i := 0;
  while i < n
     invariant 0 <= i <= n + 2
  {
     i := i + 1;
  }
  
  assert i == n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what is true at the end of a loop Dafny relies on two things.  One is the loop invariant, which it will assume is true, and the other is the loop guard (`i < n` in your case), which it will assume is false.

So immediately after the loop you can assert `0 <=i <= n+1 && !(i < n)`  This implies that `n <= i <= n+2`.  If you change the assert to

```
assert n <= i <= n+2 ;
```

That will verify.

Now, if you strengthen the invariant to

```
invariant 0 <= i <= n
```

Then you can strengthen the assert at the end to

```
 assert n <= i <= n ;
```

Or more simply

```
assert i == n ;
```

Dafny is able to infer some loop invariants that you don't tell it.  In this case it will notice that n is not changed by the loop.  Essentially it will add `n==10` as an extra loop invariant. So, if you change the invariant as I suggested, you can assert that `i==10` at the end.  But it's still only relying on the guard being false and the loop invariants (both the ones you tell it and the ones it infers on its own) being true.

For the loop you posted, Dafny is unable to infer that `i <= n` is a loop invariant, even though it may perfectly obvious to you that this is an invariant.

It would be interesting if Dafny worked backwards from the post-condition to arrive at something it might try as a loop invariant.  E.g. it might look at `i==n` and `i<n` and work out that it would need as a loop invariant `i<n || i==n` (or something stronger) and try that.  But that's not something Dafny does (yet).